# Would Blender run on Trident X Plus Gaming PC?

Tags: hardware

Please excuse my naive question - but I have only ever owned Apple Computers. I want to buy a PC computer that will handle Blender (and Unreal Engine, honestly). I am looking at an MSI Trident X Plus Gaming PC with an I9 9900 processor and NVIDIA RTX 2080ti graphics card. It supposedly runs Windows Pro - but will a GAMING computer work for Blender? Here's a link to the actual model:

[https://www.amazon.com/MSI-Trident-Plus-9SF-054US-High-End/dp/B07MPB24PH/ref=asc_df_B07MPB24PH/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MPB24PH)

Please don't beat me up too hard on this - I need advise

Comment: Blender should work like a charm on this config!

Comment: You could wait for the 3080 Extreme.  Some rumours on the street.

Comment: One day... I'll sell my left kidney and buy something similar :).

Comment: Thanks everyone!